# Button disabled not working correctly in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, button

I'm developing a **MVC** project, I have written below **javascript**  code to disable my button, actually, the button is disabled, but button click is working, how to fix it?

```
if (_isC == false) {
    $('.crt').attr('disabled', true);
    return false;      
}

<a href="createnew">             
    @Html.ActionLink("Add New Record", "myIndex", "my", new { A = "New" }, new { Class = "btn btn-primary page-scroll crt", style = "top:50px; margin-left:168px;width:120px;text-indent:-5px; position:relative;", })
</a>
```

Comment: Why do you have a link inside a link? (only the inner link is disabled) - remove the outer `<a href=" createnew" >....</a>` element

Comment: its link for create page, i want to this link,

Comment: To link to what? (`createnew()` or `myIndex()`). And if you want it to be a link, then why are you attempting to disable it. This makes no sense and its unclear what your trying to so.

Comment: it's a   myIndex , i want to disable open this myIndex Page

Comment: Then remove the outer `<a href=" createnew" ></a>` element

Comment: no , i got it, $('.crt').on('click', function () {
            return _isC; //Cancels event when _isC is false
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        });

Comment: OMG Your still need to remove that pointless outer link - what do you think its doing?

Comment: i got your advice ,its done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Html.ActionLink` will create an anchor element, you should bind the click handler

```
 $('.crt').on('click', function(){
    return _isC; //Cancels event when _isC is false
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, your answer is helpful and im edit it

 $('.crt').on('click', function () {
            return _isC; //Cancels event when _isC is false
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        });

Comment: $(this).attr('disabled', true);

Comment: @Cola, You don't need to `disable` attribute just click handler and get rid of pointless outer anchor `<a href=" createnew" ></a>`